# loading pages dynamically with jquery ajax not fully working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

below is the jquery ajax function and load.php file on the server side that supposed to load pages dynamically from different directories on my site but its not fully working. it only loads first and last pages in my nav menu `#Browse_Page1` and `#Charts_Page1` but it never loading the rest.
this is my nav menu.

```
 <nav>
 <ul id='menu' class="menu-items">
 <li><a href="#Browse_Page1" class="albums active" id="page1-link"><i class="arcd-archive"></i></br>Browse</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Top_albums_Page1" class="pages" id="page2-link"><i class="arcd-music97"></i></br>Top albums</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Top_artists_Page1" class="albums" id="page3-link"><i class="arcd-microphone52"></i></br>Top artists</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Top_lists_Page1" class="pages" id="page4-link"><i class="arcd-numbered8"></i></br>Top lists</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Charts_Page1" class="pages" id="page4-link"><i class="arcd-rising9"></i></br>Charts</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

and this is the jquery ajax function

```
  $(function () {
  $('header nav a').on('click', function () {
    var linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
    var data = {
        page      : linkClicked.replace(/\D/g, ''),
        directory : linkClicked.replace(/(_Page(.*)|#)/g,'')
    }

    $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');

    $.post('load.php', data, function(msg) {
        $('#main-content').html(msg);
        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
    }, 'html');
   });
  });
```

finally this is the load.php on server side

```
  <?php
  $page = filter_var( $_POST['page'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
  $dir  = filter_var( $_POST['directory'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if ( $page !== false && $dir !== false ) {
    $link = $dir . '/' . $dir . '_Page' . $page . '.html';
    if ( file_exists( $link ) ) {
        echo file_get_contents( $link );
    } else {
        echo 'There is no such page!';
    }
   }
 ?>
```

anyone have a idea where i am wrong or what i am missing, please help me to get out of this. thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell us what happens now and what should happen?

Comment: Your post function is working fine, I've just tested it, you need to make sure that the file you're echoing is outputting HTML or try removing the last 'html' argument in the post function call.

Comment: or you can try echoing just $link value to test if its working

Comment: @ Breedly i supposed to load pages in my navigation menu with this function and as i said it should load page in to the div  when specific link in the navigation menu clicked and it only did for 1st and last links but not loading other pages and gives the `There is no such page!` error.

Comment: @ antihate i am not echoing anything just trying to load pages by ajax to a div `<div id="main-content">` which has the `main-content` id and as you seen this id in the above function. and my problem is that this loads first and last pages of my navigation correctly but not loading the rest and gives this error `There is no such page!` please try to understand and help me its weird. please.....